# Why is no error thrown after resolve() in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, error-handling, promise

Consider the following examples:

```js
var prom1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
    sdf;
    resolve("THE_RESOLVE");  
});
```

```js
var prom2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
    resolve("THE_RESOLVE2");  
    sdf2;
});
```

After running the first example, if you inspect the current page and see the console, you will see the error:

> js:13 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: sdf is not defined
> at js:13:5
> at new Promise ()
> at js:12:21

But, for the second example, there is no error thrown for `sdf2` in the console. Initially I though `resolve/reject` acts as return statements, but any alert or console log still works after `resolve/reject` call, meaning the code after `resolve/reject` is executed, but no error is logged for it.

Is this the expected behaviour as per the official documentation? If yes, why? I haven't caught the error in `catch`.

Answer (score 4):

In the specification, [the Promise constructor does](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-executor), among other things:

> 8. Let resolvingFunctions be CreateResolvingFunctions(promise).
> 9. Let completion be Completion(Call(executor, undefined, « resolvingFunctions.[[Resolve]], resolvingFunctions.[[Reject]] »)).
> 10. If completion is an abrupt completion, then  
>     a. Perform ? Call(resolvingFunctions.[[Reject]], undefined, « completion.[[Value]] »).

If the completion of the callback is abrupt, the `reject` parameter is called with the error (the `completion.[[Value]]`). But this calling of `reject` only does something if the Promise hasn't already fulfilled. If either `resolve` or `reject` has been called previously, further calls to either are ignored. (See [CreateResolvingFunctions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createresolvingfunctions))

In your first snippet, neither is called inside the callback you're passing, and the `sdf;`'s abrupt completion results in `reject` being called, so the Promise rejects, and an unhandled rejection is logged.

In your second snippet, the Promise's state has already been set to fulfilled by the time the reference of `sdf2` throws an error, so the Promise remains resolved (and not rejected). The abrupt completion essentially gets swallowed.

You can still detect such errors with `try`/`catch` though.

```js
var prom2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
    resolve("THE_RESOLVE2");  
    try {
      sdf2;
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Man, these super technical official docs are killing me, why can't stuff be on MDN.

Comment: Hi user @CertainPerfomrance, I noticed that when setTimeout is used, the error is logged, why is that --> https://stackoverflow.com/q/74651173/3429430