# Why is error lodged after resolve() in a Promise, when setTimeout is used?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, promise

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74370916/3429430), I found that once a Promise is resolved, no errors are caught that are thrown after `resolve()`. Today, after experimenting a bit I noticed that this is not true if a setTimeout is used inside the Promise.

**Example 1 - No error caught**

```js
var prom2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
    resolve("THE_RESOLVE2");  
    throw Error("Not caught!")
    sdf2;
});
```

**Example 2 - error is caught in setTimeout**

```js
var prom2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve("THE_RESOLVE2");  
      throw Error("Caught!")
      sdf2;
    }, 500);
});
```

If you can please explain in easy language, ecmascript documentation is hard for me to understand.

Comment: `setTimeout` pushes that callback function onto the event queue. It has no concept of where `setTimeout` was called from. So you're no longer throwing an error in the context of a promise.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton In the `setTimeout`, the code still has access to `resolve` and `reject`, isn't the code still bound to Promise's context?

Comment: No, functions are just references to blocks of code. You can pass them to different contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, the `throw` is directly inside the promise executor function where the `try/catch` that it surrounds the call to the executor function with will catch the rejection.  That rejection will be ignored because at that point, the promise has already been resolved so its state can't be changed.

In the second case, the `throw` is inside the `setTimeout()` callback which has an empty callstack (it comes directly from the event loop) and thus there is nobody to catch that `throw` and the system will complain.  The promise executor function has long since returned already so the `throw` inside the `setTimeout()` callback can't be caught by it.  Remember when you call `setTimeout()`, it schedules the timer and then immediately returns and your executor callback function that you passed `new Promise()` returns (before the timer fires).

Here's an example of the implicit `try/catch` internal the promise executor function.  When you throw before calling resolve or reject, that throw will be caught internally by the promise and will reject the promise.  But, if you've already called resolve or reject, the throw will still be caught internally, but the promise state is already set and can't be changed at that point so the try/catch that catches the throw just doesn't do anything with the throw (it just eats it).

Try running this demo:

```js
function test() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        throw new Error("I threw it");
        resolve("all done");
    });
}

test().then(result => {
    console.log("resolved:", result);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("rejected:", err.message);    
});
```

Comment: So, you saying that a Promise executor function has an implicit `try/catch` block(context?) which doesn't catch errors if Promise is resolved, but with setTimeout we are basically doing `try {setTimout...}` and the function passed to setTimeout doesn't use the executer's try/catch?

Comment: @user31782 - Yes, the executor function is wrapped in it's own `try/catch` and if you `throw` before calling `resolve()`, that will reject the promise.  It will always catch the `throw` - it's just if you've already resolved the promise, then the promise state can't be changed at that point so when it catches the `throw`, it doesn't do anything.   See the example I added to my answer.

Comment: Cool... the implicit `catch` doesn't catch errors if setTimeout is used https://jsfiddle.net/y3j8nufz/

Comment: @user31782 - You don't see to understand that the `setTimeout()` callback is run on a completely different and empty stack.  The executor function is DONE and has already returned when it runs its callback and thus its `try/catch` is no longer in play.  There's no way to catch an exception in an asynchronous callback from above the scope of the callback.  The `setTimeout()` callback is called from the event loop and there's no code on the stack that has a `try/catch`.  I've tried to explain that multiple times here.

Comment: Why are you thinking I disagree with you? I get that, that's what my jsfiddle shows. The `Promise.prototype.catch` doesn't catch the error in my jsfiddle, it is the broswer which catches the error.

Comment: @user31782 - OK, I thought you were pointing out that was a problem with what I was saying rather than understanding it's how asynchronous callbacks work.  Sounds like we're good then.